# Microservice Deployment - Service Account Keys - Best Practices

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, microservices, service-accounts

**Pretext**:

- I will be explaining using Python Falsk, but it can be in any programming language.
- I give my example using Google Cloud Platform, but it can be replicated to any cloud like AWS, Azure etc..,

**Background**:

I am building a micro-service. I am using a service, say Cloud Storage: to read, write, update files. I was given a service account key (a json file) which has the required permissions.

I import the related SDK to my program, and I create a storage client object and call the related functions. In order to access the services, I have to set the path in the environment variable like below.

```
import os
os.environ['GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS'] = <service_file_path>
```

Note: there are other ways also where I can specify the path to the service account key like google-oauth2.

The code is containerized using docker and other devops files like Jenkins etc.,

The code is pushed on a version control tool like Github.

The code is deployed on a service, in my case it is: Goolge Kuberneteis engine.

**Scenario**:

while I push my code to Github (an org. account), the "service account key" which is a *secret* also has to be present along with my other code artifacts, in order for the deployment process to execute successfully (i mean with-out service access related errors).

**My Question**:

1. What are the "Best practices", with out keeping the service key exposed on Git and deploy my application successfully?
2. Which team is responsible to handle this Development team or Devops?

**Post Notes**:

I am asking from a backend developer perspective and i don't have much idea about the practices from the DevOps end.

Comment: Have a closer look to this feature on Google CLoud. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/workload-identity-federation

Comment: As you feel it, using a secret file for authentication is not safe and secure. Avoid it as much as you can!!!